# How to get a column from a tensor?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

Let's say I have a tensor consisting of 1 and 0's as shown below. How can I get the index of a specific column to replace with new values ? If I want to replace the values of column 1 with the [3.,4.,5.,6.], how do I accomplish this ?

```
a = torch.tensor([[[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
        [[0., 1., 0., 0.]],
        [[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
        [[0., 0., 0., 1.]],
        [[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
        [[0., 0., 0., 1.]],
        [[1., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling them 'columns' is a bit tricky, given that this is a 3D tensor.

This will do what you need, setting 'column' 1 to the values you gave.

```
a = torch.tensor([[[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
        [[0., 1., 0., 0.]],
        [[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
        [[0., 0., 0., 1.]],
        [[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
        [[0., 0., 0., 1.]],
        [[1., 0., 0., 0.]]])

# Change values in 'column' 1 (zero-indexed):
# The 0 is there because of the size-1 second dimension.
a[1, 0, :] = torch.tensor([3., 4., 5., 6.])

print(a)
# tensor([[[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
#         [[3., 4., 5., 6.]],
#         [[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
#         [[0., 0., 0., 1.]],
#         [[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
#         [[0., 0., 0., 1.]],
#         [[1., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Comment: One more thing how would get an element from a column ? For example, how will get element 2 from column 1 and element 3 from column 2?

Comment: Again—they're not columns. But you can again use the square brackets [] to access individual entries.

Comment: a[1, 0, :] Please the content of this list

Comment: It's a 3D tensor, so you need to provide 3 coordinates, e.g. `a[1, 0, 2]`.